# When working with Post Production Audio, Do you Work With the Original Final Cut Project?

Tags: post-production

Do people usually get to work within the original Final Cut Project? or do they get given a .mov file and separate audio files to work with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

typically you get a movie file and an OMF or AAF (which will contain all of the audio tracks and files) exported from the sequence in the Final Cut project.

Comment: Thanks. I Wasn't sure and was under the impression that I would work with the whole Final Cut Project.